# How should this Class structure be written in php? Composition, Inheritance, Decorator?

Tags: php, inheritance, composition, aggregation

I have a database where people might simultaneously be employees, customers and members of a company. My adminstration system allows me to edit the properties of the `Person`, `Employee`, `Customer` and `Member` objects on independent pages.

Now, I'd like to be able to call up an `Person` but be able to view and edit their employee, customer and member properties on the same page. Creating a view for this scenario is trivial, but I'd like to do it properly with the correct specification of base class, inheritances, compositions and aggregates, etc.

I do understand that the employees, customers and members can't exist without the person, so for my admin page, I'm thinking I should create a new class `UberDude` that is a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) of the person, employee, customer and member classes. I would also like to use this new class as part of a collection so that I could draw a table of all persons and see whether they are employees, customers or members. Something doesn't seem right and I can't work out the code for the class structure. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it true to say that Employee, Customer, and Member are all types of People (Person)?

Comment: Yes, neither of them make sense without the parent class `Person`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an inheritance issue. You have a `Person`, but then that person can be described in more specific terms such as `Employee` or `Customer`.

Normally in object-orientated programming, you start with your base class (in this instance, `Person`) and then add properties in extending sub-classes. So a `Person` may have a name, an `Employee` may then have an employee number, but this wouldn't make sense if they were a `Customer`.

What you could do is implement a decorator pattern, and just keep building on your `Person` class. I'm not sure how you're currently building people's profiles in your current application, but it would look something as follows in pseudo code:

```
<?php

$id = intval($_GET['person_id']);

$employee = new Employee(new Person($id));
```

This would instantiate your `Person` class, then that would be passed to your `Employee` class to be decorated with additional properties and methods that are specific to an employee.

Comment: How would you pull/pass in the customer and member properties? Although an employee is a person, it's not always the case that a customer is an employee.

Comment: In that case, you can then decorate with another class instead, or chain the decoration, i.e. `$person = new Customer(new Employee(new Person($id)));`. Your resultant `$person` object will then have the properties of whatever classes have been used to decorate it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unclear on how the Person class would be constructed. I'd like to continue to use the base Person class on its own without the extra employee, customer, etc properties. That is to say, I'd like two classes - a basic Person class and an all-encompasing class that I just happen to have access to on my Employee page. Sorry if it's unclear!

Comment: Well in that case, you could just construct your person class (`$person = new Person($id);`) and then create your employee class (`$employee = new Employee($person);`) or customer class (`$customer = new Customer($person);`).